# Is there any event in flexdatalist to get notified if all items loaded in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, datalist

I am putting dynamic data to flexdatalist. I want to get notified if all items loaded into flexdatalist. let's say I have hundreds of data to be inserted in the list. I want to put a callback after all data initialized/loaded to flexdatalist. How can we do this?

```js
$('.my-input').flexdatalist();
$('.my-input').on('after:flexdatalist.data', function(event, set, options) {
   alert("after")
  // callback()
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-flexdatalist/2.2.4/jquery.flexdatalist.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-flexdatalist/2.2.4/jquery.flexdatalist.js"></script>
<input type='text'
       placeholder='Programming language name'
       class='my-input'
       data-min-length='1'
       list='languages'
       name='language'
    >

<datalist id="languages">
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Cobol">Cobol</option>
    <option value="C#">C#</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="Pascal">Pascal</option>
    <option value="FORTRAN">FORTRAN</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Swift">Swift</option>
</datalist>
```

They say use 'after:flexdatalist.data' but does not seems working. However, if I type and try to search in input box 'after:flexdatalist.data' fires.

My motive is to fire a callback after all data initialized/loaded to flexdatalist. Please assist.